# Overlap images if there is not enough space to show them

Tags: android, imageview

I'm programming a little card game where the user has five cards, which shall be on the left of the screen. Let's say each card is set to have a width of 100dp. I then want the cards to be cropped accordingly and placed below each other. If the total height of the cards is too large to display them all I want them to overlap, rather than making them any smaller.

For instance, the left could be a tablet, where the space is enough, the right a smartphone where I want the cards to overlap.

[image: Example]

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working:

Code

```
public class HandCardsLayout extends RelativeLayout {

  // constructors etc..

  public void init() {
      Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
      Point size = new Point();
      display.getSize(size);
      int heightLandscape = size.y;
      int viewDistance = heightLandscape / 5;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          ImageView imageView = getImageViewAt(i);
          if(i < 4) {
              imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, -viewDistance);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Layout file

```
<de.memorian.HandCardsLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/handCard2"
        android:id="@+id/handCard1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/handCard3"
        android:id="@+id/handCard2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/handCard4"
        android:id="@+id/handCard3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/handCard5"
        android:id="@+id/handCard4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/handCard5" />
</de.memorian.HandCardsLayout>
```

This snippet overlaps the ImageViews in an uniform distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the height of your imageviews and then crop card images like that:

```
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalbitmap, 0, 0, fullViewWidth, calculatedViewHeight);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```